# ill-formated string for image extract on roslaunch

Tags: ros

I am using this simple launch script to try to extract jpg images from a 183GB rosbag.

```
<launch>
        <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="-d 2 /media/aaron/TOSHIBA\ EXT/udacity/data_2/dataset-2-2.bag"/>
        <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
        <param name="sec_per_frame" value="0.02"/>
        <param name="filename_format" value="frame%05.jpg"/>
                <remap from="image" to="center_camera/image_color"/>
        </node>
</launch>
```

but I am getting the following error,

```
PARAMETERS
 * /extract/filename_format: frame%05.jpg
 * /extract/sec_per_frame: 0.02
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.5

NODES
  /
    extract (image_view/extract_images)
    rosbag (rosbag/play)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[rosbag-1]: started with pid [12638]
process[extract-2]: started with pid [12639]
terminate called after throwing an instance of        'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::io::bad_format_string> >'
  what():  boost::bad_format_string: format-string is ill-formed
[extract-2] process has died [pid 12639, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros    /kinetic/lib/image_view/extract_images image:=center_camera/image_color __name:=extract __log:=/home/aaron/.ros/log/e34ccf72-9510-11e6-bbf0-0017c4cb3b67/extract-2.log].
log file: /home/aaron/.ros/log/e34ccf72-9510-11e6-bbf0-0017c4cb3b67/extract-2*.log
```

So the bag continues to load up to play, it takes over 30 minutes for a rosbag this size to start playing, however its not able to start the image extraction node. The topic name is correct and I can use image extract with it from rosrun but then i cant format the file name. Also, I only received 9882 jpgs out of the total 70659 using rosbag play/ rosrun extract.

Any ideas why its saying the string is ill-formated?

Comment: If your problem is solved, then mark it as such please.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the decimal type 'i' or 'd' for your `filename_format`

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag" args="-d 2 /media/aaron/TOSHIBA\ EXT/udacity/data_2/dataset-2-2.bag"/>
    <node name="extract" pkg="image_view" type="extract_images" respawn="false" output="screen" cwd="ROS_HOME">
    <param name="sec_per_frame" value="0.02"/>
    <param name="filename_format" value="frame%05d.jpg"/>
            <remap from="image" to="center_camera/image_color"/>
    </node>
```